# 4 node HyperV and shared storage cluster in Windows Server 2012

Tags: hyper-v, shared-storage

I succesfully setup a HA SOFS storage cluster using Starwind on two nodes.
Now I want to setup the HyperV failover part and need some input on how to implement this.

Do I need to add the two HyperV nodes in the storage cluster or do I need to create a seperate cluster for this?

If I need to add a seperate cluster, do I need two nics per server?

Answer (score 4):

I would create one Failover Cluster for all four nodes and place a two SOFS or CSV nodes mirrored by Starwind, depends on your needs. Here is the step-by-step guide on how to implement two nodes https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-hyper-converged-2-nodes-scenario-2-nodes-with-hyper-v-cluster

AFAIR, they have something like help me to configure the system even before purchasing, but it would be better to ask their engineers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create Highly available virtual machines then the Hyper-v host servers need to be part of a Failover Cluster. They do not need to be part of the Storage Cluster but they do need:

1) Access to the same shared storage for example a Scaled out file Server (SOFS) or a Cluster Shared Volume (CSV)

2) Be part of the same failover cluster.

so in your example you could keep you SOFS storage cluster and then create a 2 node failover cluster with your two Hyper-V Hosts. scaling out this way will make it easier to scale the two tiers in the future.

This video on Channel 9 talks about hyper-V failover clustering:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Microsoft-Campus-Days/Microsoft-Campus-Days-2013/Windows-Server-2012-R2-Hyper-V-High-Availability-with-Failover-Clustering

Windows Server 2016 has introduced a Hyper Converged model which might not be relevant for you Server 2012 deployment but does make for an interesting read:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/storage/storage-spaces/hyper-converged-solution-using-storage-spaces-direct

Comment: Perfect, I`ve setup the second cluster now. However I need to assign a withness disk now. I setup an additional disk in Starwind, but cant assign it in the HyperV cluster, It doesnt find any suitable disks. How should I fix that?

Comment: Try using a file share witness instead, the file share witness can be on any server that isn't part of the cluster, you can even create a file share witness in Azure. there some info on Quorum choices on this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612870(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: @jortiexx, did you add your quorum drive to "Available Storage" in FC after mounting it via iSCSI Initiator + formatting in NTFS?